# Linux script with 'and' and 'or' operator

Tags: linux, shell, if-statement

I have a file where i need to replace a special keyword
(thorn) to (tab) and save it back. It is working just fine with below code.

```
#Skip the header line, and translate the thorn column separators (octal 376) to tabs 
#and if there were any actual tabs in the raw file, translate them to something harmless - let's say a divide sign, octal 362
cat $input | tr '\11' '\362' | tr '\376' '\11' | tail -n 2 > $outputfile
```

**Input file**

```
1.header1þheader2þheader3
2.Thisþisþaþsample,input,thornþfile
3.forþtestingþscript
```

**Output file**

```
2.This  is  a   sample,input,thorn  file
3.for   testing script
```

Notice the comma not getting replaced, which is what we need.

However I need to tune the code in such a way that when thorn is not present then consider comma as delimiter and replace keyword comma with tab and save it back. The problem is when I am using 'or' condition then the file when have thorn is not getting saved because its not passing the criteria of comma.

```
cat $input | tr '\11' '\362' | tr '\376' '\11' || tr ',' '\11' | tail -n 2 > $outputfile
```

I am using double pipe because when thorn is present I cannot replace ','.

Basically I am trying to figure out combination of 'and' and 'or' in linux script, but it's not working like below.

```
cat $input | ((tr '\11' '\367' | tr '\376' '\11')  || (tr ',' '\11')) & tail -n +2 > newfile.csv
```

Comment: UUOC.  Use redirections instead of piping to tr.  eg `< $input tr ....`

Comment: @oguzismail i have added the input and output file.

Comment: This makes no sense. Just write a regex. `when thorn is not present then replace keyword comma with tab` sounds like a job for `sed` `/\x376/!{ s/,/\t/ }` `out combination of 'and' and 'or' in linux script` makes no sense - there is no such "combination", `tr` works on streams. You can "do" such combination - read one line, check _one line_ content, execute different action depending on the line content...

Comment: @danD : Your question is unclear to me: Does _when thorn is not present _ mean that there is no thorn anywhere in the input file, or does it mean that there is no thorn in the line being processed.

Comment: @user1934428, there wont be any thorn in the full input file.. so when thorn is present then use thorn as delimiter and when it is not present then use comma as delimiter..

Answer (score 1):

```
cat Input_file
1.header1þheader2þheader3
2.Thisþisþaþsample,input,thornþfile
3.forþthornþdelimited
4.for,comma,delimited
5.forþboth,thorn,andþcomma,delimted
```

For me, the thorn character `þ` in the above Input_File is represented by the two characters `\303\276`, and passing the above entries through this perl one-liner will produce the result that OP wanted:

```
cat Input_file | perl -ne 'if (s/\303\276/\t/g) {print} elsif (s/,/\t/g) {print} else {print}'
1.header1       header2 header3
2.This  is      a       sample,input,thorn      file
3.for   thorn   delimited
4.for   comma   delimited
5.for   both,thorn,and  comma,delimted
```

Comment: thanks for ur solution, i have done a similar code change but with if and else, i have attached the code. if u can take a look and give your comment, that will be very helpful to me

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to get the resolution myself and it is working just fine.
Below is the code attached. however if any body can suggest any issue or any better resolution, that would be highly appreciated.

```
input='inputFile.csv'

if grep -q '[\376]' $input; then
   cat $input | tr '\11' '\367'| tr '\376' '\11'
elif grep -q ',' $input; then
   cat $input | tr ',' '\11'
```